# What can Reinhardt's shield not block?

Tags: overwatch

Reinhardt's shield blocks most enemy projectiles and bullets but there are certain attacks which can go right through it. Which attacks ignore Reinhardt's shield?

Answer (score 1):

As seen [here](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/reinhardt.html#barrier) Reinhardt's barrier does not block the following:

> Melee attacks.  Reinhardt and his shield will both take full damage
> from a single melee attack.
>
> Some channeled weapons, including:
> Winston's Tesla Cannon and Symmetra's Photon Projector beam.
>
> Reinhardt's Fire Strike and Symmetra's Photon Orbs.

Fire Strike and Photon Orbs can actually pass through and damage everything in its path, including Reinhardt, his barrier and anyone else behind Reinhardt.

Comment: Symmetra's Photon Projector beam *is* blocked according to that page: "Some channeled weapons, including:  Winston's Tesla Cannon, **but Symmetra's Photon Projector beam will be blocked**."; this aligns with my experience as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Symmetra's Photon Projector can go throught the shield, maybe her Sentry Turret aswell.

Also, another Reinhardt's Fire Strike can go throught the shield.

Comment: Hanzo ult aswell

Comment: Symmetra's orbs can go through the shield, but not her beam (left-click).

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Ultimate Abilities: Hanzo, Genji, Zarya and Winston can all either hit or affect Reinhardt through the shield.